# PyQt close QMessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt, qmessagebox

So I have a QMessageBox that is not closable by the user. I want it to stay active until some work is done, and then close automatically.

I tried MsgBox.close(), but it doesn't work. How do I close that MsgBox?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found an answer. Just used MsgBox.done(1) instead of close.
Thanks

Comment: it's not work on pyqt5 still. are you sure?. in my case it always must be triggered with button without it. it wont do